# Can receive but can not send email ubuntu 20.04

Tags: email, smtp, postfix-mta, roundcube

I'm using Postfix, Roundcube 1.4.3 and devcot to receive and send emails on my vps server.

I'm able to receive emails but the errors are occurring when sending the email, the mail never reaches the destination.

Port `587` is what roundcube is using.

**Roundcube error.log**

```
[25-Dec-2021 07:18:35 +0000]: <669e8q7l> PHP Error: Connection refused (POST /?_task=mail&_unlock=loading1640416601599&_framed=1&_action=send)
[25-Dec-2021 07:18:35 +0000]: <669e8q7l> PHP Error: Failed to connect socket: Connection refused (POST /?_task=mail&_unlock=loading1640416601599&_framed=1&_action=send)
[25-Dec-2021 07:18:35 +0000]: <669e8q7l> SMTP Error: Connection failed: Failed to connect socket: Connection refused in /usr/share/roundcube/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube.php on line 1702 (POST /?_task=mail&_unlock=loading1640416601599&_framed=1&_action=send)
[25-Dec-2021 07:31:29 +0000]: <eb91q6is> PHP Error: Connection refused (POST /?_task=mail&_unlock=loading1640417491382&_framed=1&_action=send)
[25-Dec-2021 07:31:29 +0000]: <eb91q6is> PHP Error: Failed to connect socket: Connection refused (POST /?_task=mail&_unlock=loading1640417491382&_framed=1&_action=send)
```

*Error I'm getting in Roundcube ui*

```
SMTP Error (-1): Connection to server failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have anything listening on the port you are trying to send mail through. You need to configure your postfix to listen and accept mails on port 587.

Comment: If you can, please clarify more on how to do just that in the same response.